# laravel does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel

```
$orders = Orders::select('orders.id as order_id', 'collection_color.color_name as color', 'collection_color.id as collection_color_id', DB::raw('SUM(order_piece.piece) As piece'))
        ->join('order_piece', 'order_piece.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
        ->join('collection_color_size_barcode', 'collection_color_size_barcode.id', '=', 'order_piece.collection_color_size_barcode_id')
        ->join('collection_color', 'collection_color.id', '=', 'collection_color_size_barcode.collection_color_id')
        ->whereIn('orders.id', $request->order_id)
        ->groupBy('order_piece.order_id')
        ->orderBY('orders.delivery_date', 'ASC')
        ->get();
```

return $orders; => [{"order_id":30,"color":"Kahverengi","collection_color_id":21,"piece":"500"}]

```
return $ccfc = CollectionColorFabricColor::whereIn('collection_color_id', $orders->collection_color_id)->get();
```

Property [collection_color_id] does not exist on this collection instance.  i am getting error can you help me

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely due to this in your second code snippet:  `$orders->collection_color_id`. $orders is a collection, so the property doesn't exist in that object. What you actually need is to pluck those values from that collection like so:

```
return $ccfc = CollectionColorFabricColor::query()
         ->whereIn('collection_color_id', $orders->pluck('collection_color_id'))
         ->get();
```

Comment: @onur Cool. Now you can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `$orders` is collection, you need to get `collection_color_id` array like this :

```
$arrayColors = $orders->pluck('collection_color_id')->toArray();
```

then

```
return $ccfc = CollectionColorFabricColor::whereIn('collection_color_id', $arrayColors)->get();
```